# Re-arranging lines after a pattern in a file according to a specific order

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a large log file with the below format

```
date pattern1
time pattern2
variable1_name val1
variable2_name val2
variable3_name val3
variable4_name val4
date pattern1
time pattern2
variable1_name val1
variable2_name val2
variable3_name val3
variable4_name val4
```

I have created a shell script that insert those values in the database in the same order val1, val2, val3 ,val4

The problem is that the files sometimes gets corrupted and the variables come in different order, like below for example:

```
date pattern1
time pattern2
variable2_name val2
variable1_name val1
variable3_name val3
variable4_name val4
date pattern1
time pattern2
variable4_name val4
variable2_name val2
variable3_name val3
variable1_name val1
```

Using shell script, I want to rearrange the lines after pattern1 and pattern2 to be in the the same order as the original log file.

Comment: so what did you try? since you are tagging with awk and sed you may have started doing something. Please share it so we can assist!

Comment: What's the order? Numeric sort or alphabetic sort? Sort on first field or 2nd field? Something else? [edit] your question to explain how you need the input ordered.

Comment: I would change the DB import script. It should handle different orders nicely. Rearranging the log file doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Also, by inserting it into a database, you're probably giving up any guarantee of order, anyway... Better to have the queries that you run later handle the ordering instead, I would think.

Comment: When `variableX_name` are column names, use these for your `insert`-statement. In your example you might show that some fields can contain spaces.

Comment: actually i have lot of files of the same type , but this issue occurs in only one of them , i don't want to modify the insert statements

Comment: i don't want to sort , i just want to re-arrange according to a lookup file for example containing the order of the  variables that i want

Comment: i am already reformatting the file to be in the below format  

date time val1 val2 val3 val4  
date time val1 val2 val3 val4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the variable names are *not* in alphanumeric order (e.g. if variable1_name is "Nationality", variable2_name is "Height", and so on), then native sorting functions won't work. But this will:

```
sed '/pattern2/{N;N;N;N;P;h;s/.*\(variable1_name\)/\1/;P;g;s/.*\(variable2_name\)/\1/;P;g;s/.*\(variable3_name\)/\1/;P;g;s/.*\(variable4_name\)/\1/;P;d;}' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

As i can understand, you need sort blocks with variables.

There is solution with `GNU sed`.

```
sed -r 's/^time pattern[0-9]*/&/; T; {p; N; N; N; N; s/^[^\n]*\n(.*)$/echo "\1" | sort/e}'
```

Here we find `time patternN` (not as an address, all of them). With `T` we jump to end of script if we didn't find pattern (substitution wasn't successful).

Next, we print (`p`) time pattern, read four lines (`N; N; N; N`) and make new substitution.

`^[^\n]*\n` is the first line, time pattern. We don't need it.

`(.*)$` is rest part of buffer, variables, `\1`.

We replace it to `echo "\1" | sort`. It is shell command, that will be executed, 'cos we have `/e` modifier for `s`.

Output of `sort` will be delivered to `sed`'s main buffer and printed in the end of script execution.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^variable/{x;/./G;//!g;x;$!d};x;/./s/.*/echo "&"|sort/ep;z;x;/^variable/!p;d' file
```

If the line starts `variable` store it in the hold space (HS) (if the HS already has something, append it to that something). If the line does not start with `variable` check to see if the HS already holds something and if it does sort the HS,print it out and then clear it (ready for next time). If the line does not start with `variable` (edge case: last line of input it might) print it out.